# How to remove user object record edit permission for Community users

Tags: community, permissions, user, customer-community

I have some community users with license customer community. The issue I am facing is that they are able to view other users and edit and modify their details. Is there any way I can stop them from doing so? From what I can see there is no Manage User permission for Community Profile

Comment: Do they have [manage users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005253&type=1) permission or delegated admin profile?

Comment: Where do the Users see other Users and make edits? Are all Users able to view/edit each other details?

Comment: Are the users able to edit ANY other user, or only other users within the same Account?